# Regex failing again and again in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regex for first name and last name. Even when I give proper inputs according to the regex it fails. I tried changing different regexs but still it fails. For test I even used the only numbers regex but still it failed. Below is the code which I am using.

```
<form id="register_form" action="{{url('/register')}}" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" name="first_name">
      </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Number Not valid."
    );

    $("#register_form").validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: {required:true, minlength:2, regex:"^[a-zA-Z]+((\\s|\\-)[a-zA-Z]+)?$"},
        },
        messages:   {
            first_name:{required:'First name is required',minlength:'First name should contain atleast two alphabets',regex:'Only alphabets allowed and it should not start with space.'},
        }
    );
</script>
```

My input which fails is Raj Shah, this should work perfectly fine. I checked for duplicate input id but there is none. I checked the regex on online tester there it works fine.

Comment: Try not to use `new RegExp` when you can avoid it - use a regular expression literal instead so you don't have to double-escape `\\`.

Comment: the first regex string you have will match `"First"` `"First Last"` and `"First-Last"` - perhaps you are using `validator.addMethod` incorrectly

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `re.test('Raj Shah');` -> `true` It's not the regex.

Comment: My guess is the `regexp` parameter may not be passed in correctly - a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example would help

Comment: in `regex:"^[a-zA-Z]+((\\s|\\-)[a-zA-Z]+)?$"` ... what does the `regex:` key mean? please try to show more **meaningful** code to get more **meaningful** help

Comment: @JaromandaX My input tag is this : `<input type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" name="first_name">` and I am using the above regex to allow names that can have a single space in their first name for eg: "Lee Wo". The problem is that till yesterday it was working fine, all of sudden today it is failing all the regex which I use. I have added the regex in jquery form validator rules. I tried `regex: "^(?!(\s))([a-zA-Z\s])*$"` to allow more than 1 space.

Comment: with no context `regex: "blah blah doesn't matter"` makes no sense at all ... you have not responded to a simple request ... in what way is `regex: "...."` used by your code

Comment: @JaromandaX please check i have edited my code in the question.

Comment: thank you!! that wasn't hard! Now, what makes you think your `regex:` will be passed to `function(value, element, regexp)` as the third argument?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have taken the adding a validator method part from the internet. I found the same method in 4 5 different sites.

Comment: right ... so, because you added a `regex` key to `rules.first_name` it is automatically passed as the **third** argument to the method you added that is called `regex` - I don't see validator working that way, but then I don't use it, so

Comment: Ok, you said your regex checks out. What you have in the question has this value: `^[a-zA-Z]+((\s|\-)[a-zA-Z]+)?$` Which would match 1 word or two with 1 space or dash separating the words. So now I wonder how `regex:"thing"` or `"regex",` become passed in as `regexp` with a `p`. This BTW isn't going to work for names with accents or unicode characters. Also some people's first or last name is dashed or spaced and still correct.

Comment: @dlamblin I tried checking the regex in 2 3 different regex testers online, there the regex works fine, as expected. Okay I will search for a regex which will accept accents or unicode characters too.

Comment: @RajShah the unicode doesn't seem to be a problem. But to save you that trouble: `re = /^\p{L}+((\s|-)\p{L}+)?$/u` `r = re.exec('My vönName')` produces `["My vönName", " vönName", " ", index: 0, input: "My vönName", groups: undefined]`

Answer (score 0):

While your regex pattern seems to work fine, the problem could lie on how the regex pattern was passed, it could have undergone an escaping process where your backslash character is escaped again by adding another backslash before it.

You can try logging the `regex` string to the console if you can either see atleast 3 backslashes instead of 2.

You should also try using `single quotes` instead of `double quotes` so that the backslash character will not be interpolated in your string..

```
'^[a-zA-Z]+((\\s|\\-)[a-zA-Z]+)?$'
```

instead of

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+((\\s|\\-)[a-zA-Z]+)?$"
```

You may also try adding a `third` backslash to your regex:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+((\\\s|\\\-)[a-zA-Z]+)?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

While your regex isn't faulty and your input should pass, you seem to be having issues with the validator logic. I'm not sure this is going to help, but I would recommend naming the `regex` argument and `regexp` parameter the same just in case that's the issue, and then compiling the `regexp` once outside the validation method.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  "regex",
  function(value, element, regex) {
    return this.optional(element) || regex.test(value);
  },
    "Number Not valid."
  );
$("#register_form").validate({
  rules:
    {
      first_name: {
        required:true,
        minlength:2,
        regex:/^\p{L}+((\s|-)\p{L}+)?$/u},
      },
      messages: {
        first_name:{
          required:'First name is required',
          minlength:'First name should contain at least two letters',
          regex:'Only letters allowed and it should not start with space.'},
});
```